# Why vite-plugin-federation don't build remote project redux

Tags: reactjs, vite, micro-frontend, federation

Within my micro-frontend project, each individual project has its own Redux and state configuration.

When I export the project without Redux, it works, displaying 'Hello world!' on the screen. However, when I add the provider, I encounter an error.

**Host**

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import { BuildePage } from "builder/pages";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense>
      <BuilderPage />
    </Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Remote**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '@/store';

const BuilderPage = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <span>Hello world!</span>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default BuilderPage;
```

**Errors**

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlkDE.png)

[All of them null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66ojH.png)